# How to create NSData from a string and an image together and decompile this NSData to a string and an image before

Tags: ios

I've got an problem with it,Can you help me! Thank you so much!
NSString *mystring;
UIImage *image;
NSData *data = ... include data of string and image and can decompile to them like before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in following manner

```
NSString *aStrImageName     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"splash_ipad.png"];
    UIImage *aImg               = [UIImage imageNamed:aStrImageName];
    NSDictionary *aDictData     = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:aStrImageName,@"ImageName",aImg,@"Image", nil];
    NSData *aObjData            = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:aDictData];
    NSDictionary *aDictBack     = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:aObjData];
    NSString *aStrImageNameBack = [aDictBack valueForKey:@"ImageName"];
    UIImage *aImgBack           = [aDictBack objectForKey:@"Image"];
```

Comment: HI Rajesh, how can I get back my string and my image like them before

Comment: @user3652608 The last line of the code does it. (Read NSKeyedUnarchiver). You bget back a dictionary, from which you extract your objects using the predefined keys.